# $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

This action induces the homomorphism $\phi:GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)\to S_4$, which is injective. Would it be correct to explicitly list the elements of $im(\phi)$ as the matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Comment: It's not injective (or do you mean $S_3$?). And do you know what "${\rm im}(\phi)$" means?

Comment: Note, that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong S_3$. If your homomorphism $\phi$ is injective, then image $\mathrm{Im}\phi \cong S_3$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that $\vec{0}$ does not "participate" in permutations, so yes, $S_3$.

Comment: @anon, yes, an element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is taken to a permutation in $S_3$. But we define those permutations by matrix multiplication. For example, we could say that $\pi_I \in S_3$ is $I$. Correct?

Comment: @sequence, you can freely act on $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ by permutations, so your initial $S_4$ was not incorrect (moreover, it made more sence). I guess that you mean that this action **is defined by** the homomorphism $\phi: GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)\to S_4$.

Comment: @Glinka, but what about $\vec{0}\in \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$? It is not permuted under any permutations, and thus it stays "fixed" under all of them. Shouldn't this imply that the codomain of $\phi$ is $S_3$?

Comment: We define permutations as functions, without making any reference to matrices. (Replying to Glinka's comment below: oops yes, I was mixing it up with surjection for whatever reason.)

Comment: If you don't lay additional constraints on this action, then no element has to be fixed. See the definition of the group action. It's still not quite clear what you're asking though. Where does this question come from? Btw, @anon wasn't right, when he said that $\phi$ is not injective, if it bothers you. I guess he confused it with surjection.

Comment: @sequence, if you have any questions left, don't hesitate to contact me (in chat room here on mse, or in skype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image $\mathrm{Im}\phi=\phi(A)=\{\phi(a)\}_{a\in A}=\{b\in B\ |\ \ \exists a\in A: \phi(a)=b \}$ of the homomorphism $\phi: A\to B$ is a subgroup of $B$. So if you map a group of matrices to a permutation group, then the elements of $\mathrm{Im}\phi$ are permutations. So no, it wouldn't be correct to list the elements of $\mathrm{Im}\phi$ as matrices, but it would be correct to list them as permutations.